# copy elision using STL (vector as example)

Tags: c++, copy-elision

I was reading about the copy elision in c++. And i was having doubts about STL in c++ using this copy elision.

The following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> merge(vector<int> &arrA, vector<int> &arrB)
{
    int x;
    vector<int> result;

    for(x = 0; x < arrA.size(); x++)
    {
        result.push_back(arrA[x]);
    }
    for(x = 0; x < arrB.size(); x++)
    {
        result.push_back(arrB[x]);
    }
    cout << "fun return: " << &result <<endl;
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> arrA;
    arrA.push_back(1);
    vector<int> arrB;
    arrB.push_back(2);
    vector<int> res;

    res = merge(arrA, arrB);
    cout << "return: "  << &res <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So I was doing a simple task (merging) the vectors A and B (do not pay attention to the process, just the function and return.

```
vector<int> merge(vector<int> &arrA, vector<int> &arrB)
```

With the following definition it is returning a `vector<int>` (no reference)

And also `return result;` which is the variable declared in the function scope.

I was trying to see the memory address at which these vectores are located.
output:

```
==5036== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5036== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5036== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5036== Command: ./a.out
==5036== 
fun return: 0xffefffe40
return: 0xffefffe20
==5036== 
==5036== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5036==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5036==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 28 bytes allocated
==5036== 
==5036== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5036== 
==5036== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5036== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The memory address is different for both so I was thinking that as long as it will no make a copy-construtor, it will be the same memory address at the end (0xffefffe40) Does that means it is copy-constructed?

Is this method being copy elision?

- if not:   why it is not copy elision?
- if yes:   How can I know it is really doing the copy elision?

And the important one: if this is not being copy elision, is it possible to do it? what is needed in order to do the copy elision in STL?

Comment: This question is not about copy elision in"STL" (whatever that is intended to refer to), but about copy elision in user-written code.

Comment: Try `vector<int> res = merge(arrA, arrB);`, instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks!, so according to that. The copy-elision happens only when the delcaration is in the same line as the function calling. is that correct?

Comment: The problem is there is no copy to elide otherwise. You are assigning the return value of a function to an existing object. This will invoke the existing object's assignment operator, rather than a copy-constructor.

Answer (score 1):

For copy elision, you need to have the "copy" in the first place, i.e. your `res` vector has to be copy constructed from the return value.
Otherwise you'll just have an assignment, which requires getting rid of whatever was in the vector and as such cannot be elided.

Notice that it would still be a move assignment, so the drawback won't be that much (You can test it with memcheck too).